# resharper search with pattern for using(... new System.Data.Linq.DataContext)

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-5.0, structural-search

I am attempting to search for

```
using (var context = new $DataContext$())
```

where DataContext is any class that extends `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` using Resharpers 'Search with Pattern'.

The pattern I'm using is:

```
using($type$ $var$ = new $type$($args$))
{
  $stmt$
}
```

[image]

This appears to return *all* using statements, eg using StreamWriter, using FileStream, things that clearly do not derive from `System.Data.Linq.DataContext`

How can you return only the types indicated?

I am using VS 2010 SP1 Beta and ReSharper 5.1 C# Edition build 5.1.1727.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you file it as a bug, because the following returns the expected results:

```
$type$ $var$ = new $type$($args$);
```

(Settings like you showed them).
It returns only this line:

```
var context2 = new DataContext("");
```

But not this:

```
var stream2 = new FileStream("", FileMode.CreateNew);
```

Comment: what R# and VS are using? please include version numbers and/or service packs

Comment: I am currently using VS 2010 without SP and R# Build 5.1.1753.4

Comment: I have posted to r# discussion forum. http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5290066#5290066

Comment: Did you try the statement using 'using' and have it return unexpected results like it did for me?

Comment: Yes. And it behaves as you described. That's why I tried it without the `using`. That's why I suggested it is a bug: In some circumstances it works, in others, it doesn't.

Comment: This is a bug as confirmed by Jetbrains. See http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5290193#5290193